# Allow/Disallow application access using the global.asax events

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-2.0, global-asax

I have an ASP .NET web application (runs only on the Intranet) where I am using a simple user authorization model.  I have a table called tblApplicationAccess which has TWO fields – UserID and AccessLevel.

For example, 
UserID: John.Smith, Access Level: 2

(1 – General Access, 2 – Data Entry Access, 3 – Super User, 4 – Developer Access)

I am using the **Session_Start** event in global.asax to authorize the user. Here is the code,

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strUserID = User.Identity.Name.Substring(5);
        bool isAllowedToView = false;

        // UtilityClass is a root level class with various methods that I use throughout the application. 
        // QUESTION: Could this be the problem? Since it is at root level (alongside all the pages), could it be the case that this resource isn't checked for user access?  

        UtilityClass.StrCurrentSessionID = this.Session.SessionID;

        // Add a row to BLSC_tblSession
        int nRowsReturned;
        string strConnectionString = UtilityClass.GetConnectionString("My Application");
        string strQueryStartSession = "INSERT INTO BLSC_tblSession " +
                                      "(SessionID, UserID, SessionStatus, StartTime, EndTime) " +
                                      "VALUES ('" + this.Session.SessionID + "', '" + User.Identity.Name.Substring(5) + "', 'Active', '" + DateTime.Now + "', '" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) + "')";
        SqlConnection connStartSession = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        if (connStartSession != null)
        {
            try
            {
                connStartSession.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlStartSession = new SqlCommand(strQueryStartSession, connStartSession);

                nRowsReturned = sqlStartSession.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (nRowsReturned == 0)
                    throw new Exception("Session could not be started.");
                else
                {
                    // Authorize User
                    // Check if user has access to the application. If not, redirect to UnauthorizedAccess.aspx
                    // Check for access level 1.
                    // IMPORTANT: For Dev server change access level to 4.
                    isAllowedToView = UtilityClass.CheckUserAccess(strUserID, 1);
                    if (isAllowedToView == false)
                    {
                        UtilityClass.WriteToLog("Application Access Denied: UserID - " + strUserID, 1);
                        Response.Redirect("Some URL");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Browser detection
                        string strBrowserName = Request.Browser.Browser;
                        if (strBrowserName != "IE")
                        {
                            UtilityClass.WriteToLog("Non-supported browser usage detected: UserID - " + strUserID + ", Browser - " + strBrowserName, 0);
                            Response.Redirect("Some other URL");
                        }
                    }
                }
                connStartSession.Close();

            }
            catch (SqlException SqlEx)
            {
                UtilityClass.HandleError("Global.asax", "Session_Start", SqlEx.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                UtilityClass.HandleError("Global.asax", "Session_Start", Ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connStartSession != null)
                    connStartSession.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

**UtilityClass.CheckUserAccess**

```
public static bool CheckUserAccess(string UserID, int RequiredAccessLevel)
    {
        bool bReturn = false;
        object TemporaryPlaceHolder;
        int nUserAccessLevel = 0;
        string strQueryCheckUserAccess = "SELECT AccessLevel " + 
                                         "FROM BLSC_tblApplicationAccess " +
                                         "WHERE UserID = '" + UserID + "'";
        string strConnectionString = GetConnectionString("My Application");
        SqlConnection connCheckUserAccess = null;
        try
        {
            if (strConnectionString != String.Empty)
            {
                connCheckUserAccess = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
                connCheckUserAccess.Open();

                if (connCheckUserAccess != null)
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCheckUserAccess = new SqlCommand(strQueryCheckUserAccess, connCheckUserAccess);

                    TemporaryPlaceHolder = sqlCheckUserAccess.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (TemporaryPlaceHolder != DBNull.Value && TemporaryPlaceHolder != null)
                    {
                        nUserAccessLevel = Convert.ToInt32(TemporaryPlaceHolder);
                        if (nUserAccessLevel >= RequiredAccessLevel)
                            bReturn = true;
                        else
                            bReturn = false;
                    }
                    else
                        bReturn = false;
                }
                connCheckUserAccess.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException SqlEx)
        {
            HandleError("UtilityClass.cs", "CheckUserAccess", SqlEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            HandleError("UtilityClass.cs", "CheckUserAccess", Ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connCheckUserAccess != null)
                connCheckUserAccess.Close();
        }
        return bReturn;
    }
```

**The Problem:** 
My application does not load in the production environment.

The application runs using Windows Authentication. To be precise, we have ***DomnainName\ApplicationServer$*** accessing SQL Server and not individual users.

**My Question:**

If I want to check application access using my current model and the global.asax events, where is the best place to put it? Am I doing something grossly wrong here? I need to write to the session table for logging events and cannot use role-based authentication that ASP .NET provides.

Comment: What you mean saying "My application does not load"? Any exceptions from EventLog / custom logs / anything happens in Application_Error()

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have code to handle application level error in the Application_Error() event where I am re-directing to a generic error page. Nothing happens.

Comment: So it does not entering in Application_Error at all?

Comment: Nope, it does not even go into the Application_Error. Here is what I found. The URL I have is something like http://domain/Home/MyApplication. All the users can still go to http://domain/Home ... so it is definitely some problem with the Session_Start as I have nothing in Application_AthenticateRequest or Application_AuthorizeRequest. I wonder if I should authorize the user in Application_AuthorizeRequest. I will update you. Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspectives `SessionStart` looks as a good place to do such things. 
At first try to figure out why it does not load in production and see whether any unhandled exceptions are occur

1. Try out add logs in the `protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)`
   in the `global.asax` file
2. Subscribe for [HttpApplication.Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.error.aspx)
3. See Windows EventLog

Comment: Problem Solved: The way I am doing this is correct. The problem caused by a dormant table with a FOREIGN KEY constraint. Life is good :)

Comment: So how do you figured it out?

Comment: Hi sllev, I ran it in debug mode using the identity of one user who was denied access. And Bingo!

Comment: sllev ... thanks for your support. "From my perspectives SessionStart looks as a good place to do such things." was the confidence booster.

Comment: Cool, my greetings :) Debug mode this is a gret thing!